# Resizing Image along with window's size change in Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a few questions about showing an image file in kivy.

I'm developing a sight-playing training application with kivy. I'd like to show a score png file like following.

[image]

After that, I'd like scroll this from right to left automatically.

First, when I resize the window, the score is extended too much like following. I'd like to keep image's ratio. Would you tell how to do this?

[image]

kv file

```
FloatLayout:
    Image:
        size_hint: self.image_ratio, 1
        keep_ratio: False
        allow_stretch: True
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: 1,1,1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        source: 'score.png'
```

py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color
from kivy.core.window import Window

class ScoreViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    ScoreViewApp().run()
```

Second, which below way should I choose, to show an image file in kivy?

1. Drawing Rectangle with the image texture on widget's canvas
2. Using Image widget loading the image as a source

Would you tell me why? I don't know the difference between these.

Last, I made the Image widget's background white by drawing a white rectangle on the canvas.before. I instructed this just on canvas first, but it showed only a white screen without the score png. After that, I did on canvas.before instead. I was able to show a score on a white background. Would you tell me why to instruct it on canvas."before?"

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Change `keep_ratio: False` to `True`, or just remove that line from your Kivy file and your image will keep it's ratio.

Comment: I did that, but the changed program showed only a white screen without score png.

Comment: I dont know why. I tried it and it worked...